# AWS API Gateway HTTP API: How to modify the api response before it is returned to the api caller

Tags: aws-api-gateway, httpresponse, aws-http-api

In AWS API Gateway HTTP API, how can I modify the api response before it is returned to the api caller? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot.

From the [AWS API Gateway docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html):The keys that can currently be modified are `Header` and `Status Code`.